# symfony2: always i have cleaning the cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, symfony-2.3

I work with symfony2 , the problem when I change a twig file, the change does not appear, after I clear the cache the modification appears, I can not work like that... Any idea ?

Comment: Try turning off caching in development then

Comment: Try access your app through app_dev.php instead of app.php

Comment: Using the `prod` environnement, TWIG doesn't compile its files *"on the fly"*. It uses the already compiled files into the cache directory. This compilation occurs when you clear the cache for the prod environnement. If you don't want to clear the cache for each TWIG modification, you should switch your environnement to `dev` instead

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are testing in the Production mode, try testing in the Development mode,

```
http://yourhost/app_dev.php
```

`http://yourhost/app.php`  is for prod, which always uses cache, I don't know if there's a way you can prevent it from caching your changes.

> If you want to see modifications directly in your prod.. you may want
>   to install your assets (if you don't see changes made on images or
>   css) **which is not your case here**.

This link may help

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Answer (score 1):

In symfony2 there are many running environments development, production, test... If you are running on production it doesn't check if files has been changed to improve performance however if you use the test environment symfony will check for modification.

To run in development mode you need use app_dev.php : `http://localhost/app_dev.php/your_route`

Remember this only works if you are on the same machine as your web server.

Comment: you can comment (or replace by authorization which is more secure than just comment) part of  `app_dev.php` responsible for this check and get access from any machine